# java HashMap keys comparison with low throughput

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to check keys of origMap with otherMap .if it found take the value from othermap as key and value of origMap as value

place it into new hashmap. if not found calculate the all values of origmap using Bigdecimal place in the same map as key "other" and value as bigdecimal output. I am trying like below but it's not working throwing null pointer,not sure what is the issue.

Maps:

```
HashMap < String, Object > origMap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
origMap.put("test", "1");
origMap.put("test2", "100.00");
origMap.put("test3", "3");
origMap.put("test4", "300.23");

HashMap < String, Object > otherMap = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
otherMap.put("test3", "fee");
otherMap.put("test2", "tax");
```

code:

```
Map newMap = new HashMap();
BigDecimal value1 = null;
for (Map.Entry <? , ?> me: origMap.entrySet())
{
    String key = "";
    String value = "";
    if (otherMap.get(key).equals(me.getKey()))
    {
        key = otherMap.get(me.getKey()).toString();
        value = origMap.get(me.getKey()).toString();
        newMap.put(key, value);
    }
    else
    {
        value = origMap.get(me.getKey()).toString();
        value1 = value1.add(new BigDecimal(value));
    }

    queryMap.put("others", value1);
}
```

Comment: stack oveflow not allowing to add code i am trying.

Comment: As for the NullPointerException please mark the line where it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`otherMap.get(key)` will not find an entry for `key=""` and thus the call to `equals(...)` will throw a NPE.

Since you seem to try and check whether there is an entry for `me.getKey()` in `otherMap` try `otherMap.get(me.getKey()) != null` or `otherMap.containsKey(me.getKey()=)` instead.

Additionally, `otherMap.get(key).equals(me.getKey())` will never be true in your case (independent on the value of `key`), since you're comparing the value from `otherMap` with the key from `origMap`.

Also please note that calling `toString()` might result in a NPE as well, unless you are sure that there are no null values.

I'll try and restructure your code to what I think you want:

```
Map<String, String> newMap=new HashMap<>(); //as of Java 7
BigDecimal value1=null;
for (Map.Entry<String,Object> me : origMap.entrySet()) {  
  if(otherMap.containsKey( me.getKey() )) {
    Object otherValue = otherMap.get(me.getKey());
    Object origValue =  origMap.get(me.getKey());
    String key = otherValue != null ? otherValue.toString() : null; //note: this might cause problems if null keys are not allowed
    String value = origValue != null ? origValue.toString() : null;
    newMap.put(key, value);
  }else {
    Object origValue =  origMap.get(me.getKey());
    if( origValue != null ) {
      value1=value1.add(new BigDecimal( origValue.toString())); //note: this might cause NumberFormatException etc. if the value does not represent a parseable number
    }
  }

  queryMap.put("others", value1);
}
```

Btw, why are `origMap` and `otherMap` of type `Map<String, Object>` if all values are strings? In that case `Map<String, String>` would fit better, thus removing the need for the `toString()` calls (and the null checks as well).

Comment: is any in build methods are there to prevent null pointer exception.and also here i am checking 1 key to n keys. how to optimize this.

Comment: which hashmap i have to use to exclude null keys or values automatically,if either key or value has null or empty

Comment: @user2684215 depends on what you want to achieve. It would also quite easy to do that yourself.